# Youtube API playVideo() function does not count toward views. Does that affect monetization?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-iframe-api

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#playVideo):

> player.playVideo():Void
>
> Plays the currently cued/loaded video. The final player state after this function executes will be playing (1).
>
> Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

How does this affect monetization? if I use the playVideo() function on my site and the views don't get counted, do content creators (with appropriate accounts) still get paid for their views? I don't want to be stealing from content creators.

Comment: There's actually some controversy about this, especially with Facebook and YouTube: https://medium.com/@hankgreen/theft-lies-and-facebook-video-656b0ffed369. I think the general idea is that unless the video is being played natively on YouTube, there's no way the Content ID system/monetization policy can figure out that the views should go to the content creator so that they can be properly compensated.

Comment: That *sort of* makes sense for non-native players, but with the iframe API, whether a script-triggered JS function runs playVideo() or a user's onclick mouse event runs playVideo() under the hood shouldn't matter at all. (I wish the devs actually gave support on the forum they direct customers to for support so important issues like this could be resolved.)

Comment: How would you prevent botting views then?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Did you ever figured out a solution?